# Python events & triggers

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, events, python-class

Is there a way to trigger CHILD objects in Python? So what I mean:

```
class A(object):
  def a(self):
    print("Hello from A")
    # ???

class B(A)
  def b(self):
    print("Now in B")
```

and I need to trigger the `b()` function from class `A`, and `A` only "knows" that `B` class extends to it

I want to use it for events in something like plugins, so there will be some modules with classes which extends main class, from which I'll trigger events in plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an abstract plugin type as an interface for which function can be called:

```
class AbstractPlugin(object):
  def trigger(self):
    pass

class APlugin(AbstractPlugin):
  def trigger(self):
    print("This is plugin A")

class BPlugin(AbstractPlugin):
  def trigger(self):
    print("This is plugin B")
```

With your class A, you could do stuff like this:

```
class A(object):
  def a(self, plugin: AbstractPlugin):
    print("Hello from A")
    plugin.trigger()

master = A()
plugin_a = APlugin()
plugin_b = BPlugin()

master.a(plugin_a)
master.a(plugin_b)
```

This will result in:

```
Hello from A
This is plugin A
Hello from A
This is plugin B
```

Comment: But I want to call function in B inside A, so the only way I run functions inside B is to call them from A

Comment: But why is B inherited from A then? What you are showing in your example is that B is of type A. Therefore it is the consequence to call B-specific methods using an interface A provides. Could you please elaborate on this inheritance?

Comment: So in your example when I call a() from class A it uses A's function b(), but I want to call B's function b().

Comment: I added a small example for you to see, how b() from B gets called. Does that help?

Comment: I tried that, but, how I said before, I need to go to B's function b() from A class

Comment: Ok, sorry for not understanding you in the first place. I was confused because of the inheritance of A and B. Would it be possible, to define A.a() as def a(self, b: B) and calling b.b() in a()? If you need this not only from B but from C and D as well, you may want to define an interface to be called. I can create a more detailled example if you think this may be a viable solution.

Comment: Yes, you correctly understand, I want to do this for many classes, but idk how...

Comment: I have updated my answer. Does this fit your purpose?

Comment: Yeah, it's much better now and it works! And the last question: can I get a list of class by their extension? Because in this case I need to know the names of classes. Of course it's not a big problem, I think it'll be better to name main classes simple "Main", but if I need, is there a way?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by „a list of class by their extension“. Could you try to explain it a bit more and maybe with other words? By the way: Sorry for answering late, but I can’t be on SO the whole weekend :)

Comment: Oh, it’s OK. The problem is solved now, thanks!